# Laravel Scheduling Task on AWS is not working

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-scheduler

I am deploying my Laravel application to ElasticBeanstalk environment. I am trying to run a command in the Scheduling Task on the server. But it is not working. This is what I have done.

I schedule my command in the Kernel.php file as follow.

```
$schedule->command('counter:update')->everyMinute()->onOneServer();
```

I am using Redis as my cache driver and it is working.

Then I tried two different approaches.

**First Approach: Using Laravel AWS Worker package**, https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker

I installed the package following the instructions mentioned in the doc.

Then I whitelist the worker routes mentioned in the doc in the CSRF middleware.

Then I created a cron.yml file right inside the project's root folder with the following content.

```
version: 1
cron:
  - name: "schedule"
    url: "/worker/schedule"
    schedule: "* * * * *"
```

Then I deployed my application. But the Scheduling task is not working. So I tried the second approach as follow.

**Second Approach: Using Crontab**

I created a .ebextensions/cronjob.config file with the following content.

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

Then I deployed my application.
The second approach is not working either. What is missing in my configuration and how can I get it working?

This is my another cronjob.config file.

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            date > /tmp/date
            * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `cron.yml` you tried is only for **worker environments**.

The `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` is only for **Amazon Linux 1**. Since you are using `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running PHP 7.3` (as I recall), the cron  will error out.

Thus, you should focus on the second approach, which is in line with **AWS blog** on how to use cron on AL2:

- [How do I create cron jobs on Amazon EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk environments?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/)

Therefore, I would recommend execute `cron` job through a script (e.g., `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`) as shown in the blog.

Modified content for `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`.

You can try first only with `date > /tmp/date` just to check if the cron job works. For this you have to deploy your application, and check if `/tmp/date` contains the time generated by this script.

```
    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            date > /tmp/date

            # the line below is commented out.
            #/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

            exit 0
```

#### Access environment variables in Amazon Linux 2

The env variables are stored in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`

Thus to load them in your script you can use the following:

```
env $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) sh -c '/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1'
```

or in two lines

```
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) 
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217857/discussion-on-answer-by-marcin-laravel-scheduling-task-on-aws-is-not-working).

Comment: @SamuelLiew what are comments for if not for extended discussion?

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure out why my scheduler wasn't working anymore after a plateform update. Thanks for pointing to the right env var path!

Comment: @FabriceLefloch No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: I have been chasing this forever. This is the only solution that works. I would vote this up 100 times if I could.