# Scheduled task on AWS Elastic beanstalk not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cron-task

I have a Laravel application running on EC2 instance handled by Elastic Beanstalk.
To handle some cron job I used the script provided by AWS here https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/cron-leaderonly-linux.config
And some extra informations provided by Macin in this thread [Laravel Scheduling Task on AWS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886323/laravel-scheduling-task-on-aws-is-not-working/62886505#62886505)

Everything is working exactly as they should on my staging environment, but in production the cron task doesn't seem to be triggered.

Both environnement are supposed to be exactly the same (platform version is "PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2").
I tried to run `sudo service crond status` and I can see this line at the time I deployed the app `(*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/cron_example)`.

Also in `/var/log/cron` file I can see for everyminute `(root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/cron_example.sh)` so it seems like everything is running fine, but  `/tmp/cron_example.log` isn't created and my real task isn't executed either.

Does anyone has an idea on what I could do to understand what is blocking it? Is there some extra log file I could consult to find out what is going on?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of AWS technical team I was finally able to fix this CRON not running error.
It turns out that the IAM role which was making the deployment in my ElasticBeanstalk didn't have the ec2:DescribeTag role (it was having the elasticbeanstalk:DescribeTag role).
At that time I still don't know why the exact same role were running correctly on my staging environment and not in the production one.

Comment: Which role maked deployment, Codepipeline one or ec2 role or beanstalk role?

Comment: The IAM user making the deployment has the elasticbeanstalk role

Comment: Can you please show a sample cron config you have done in ebextension or hooks?

Comment: You should have a look at the file provided in my first message https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/cron-leaderonly-linux.config you have to place it in your .ebextensions folder. You just have to take care that the IAM user running the deployment has the correct roles

Comment: Made it working, just a different way to get env vars in cron now

Comment: @ManojKumar Can you explain how you solved it ?