# Laravel Cron Jobs on Elastic Beanstalk AWS Linux 2

Tags: php, linux, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8

I have been trying to get cron jobs working for Laravel on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Something in the AWS Linux 2 AMI seems to have broken this process and it seems that cron jobs are not firing.

I have tried all the solutions in this post:
[How do I setup and use Laravel Scheduling on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096921/how-do-i-setup-and-use-laravel-scheduling-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Yet none of them seem to work.

Has anyone gotten this to work on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with the Linux 2 AMI?

Answer (score 0):

After tons of searching and struggling, I found the answer here.

[Laravel Scheduling Task on AWS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886323/laravel-scheduling-task-on-aws-is-not-working?rq=3)